# How Moles Isolation framework is implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moles, isolation-frameworks

[Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) is an isolation framework created by Microsoft.  A cool feature of Moles is that it can "mock" static/non-virtual methods and sealed classes (which is not possible with frameworks like Moq).  Below is the quick demonstration of what Moles can do:

```
Assert.AreNotEqual(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), DateTime.Now);

// MDateTime is part of Moles; the below will "override" DateTime.Now's behavior
MDateTime.NowGet = () => new DateTime(2012, 1, 1); 
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), DateTime.Now);
```

Seems like Moles is able to modify the CIL body of things like `DateTime.Now` at runtime.  Since Moles isn't open-source, I'm curious to know which mechanism Moles uses in order to modify methods' CIL at runtime.  Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: I highly recommend watching these 3 videos of @Peli explaining how Pex and Moles work.  They are very good! [Video Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-13 "Microsoft PEX/MOLES & advanced Unit-Testing aspects 1/3"); [Video Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-23 "Microsoft PEX/MOLES & advanced Unit-Testing aspects 2/3"); [Video Part 3](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-33 "Microsoft PEX/MOLES 3/3")

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Moles implements a CLR profiler (in particular the [ICorProfilerCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230818.aspx) interface) that allows to rewrite MSIL method bodies before they are compiled into assembly code by the .NET runtime. This is done in particular through the [JitCompileStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230586.aspx) callback.

In each method, Moles introduces a detour that looks like this:

```
static struct DateTime 
{
    static DateTime Now
    {
        get 
        {
            Func<DateTime> d = __Detours.GetDelegate(
                null, // this point null in static methods
                methodof(here) // current method token
                );
            if(d != null)
                return d();
            ... // original body
        }
    }
}
```

When you set a mole, your delegate is stored in the underlying __Detours dictionary which gets looked up whenver the method is executed.

Comment: +1 for actually expaining HOW That works. I was curious, too. Nice to know  there actually IS a way to rewrite a method in debug mode ;)

Comment: +1 from me as well - I was wondering how they did it and chanced upon this - makes sense as well.

Comment: I highly recommend watching these 3 videos of @Peli explaining how Pex and Moles work.  They are very good! [Video Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-13 "Microsoft PEX/MOLES & advanced Unit-Testing aspects 1/3"); [Video Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-23 "Microsoft PEX/MOLES & advanced Unit-Testing aspects 2/3"); [Video Part 3](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-33 "Microsoft PEX/MOLES 3/3")

Answer (score 0):

This is working like as wrapper to any assembly you want, for example `mscorlib` (this example baseing on Moles Assembly Wrapper of `mscorlib`). This giving to you power to **replace any .NET method by the delegate written by coder**.

This is not working automagicaly. You must first create before this start works, *Moles XML configuration* file with list of Assemblies to "Wrapper" and by this code Moles generate a References of this assembiles from config file. And you must in this file add `using namespace System.Moles`, and before function `[HostType("Moles")]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a presentation titled "Moles: Tool-Assisted Environment Isolation With Closures". Note the ending, "WITH CLOSURES". It was written in 2010. One of the authors was Jonathan de Halleux. I will assume that this is the formal first name of Peli de Halleux. This paper can be found in the book "Objects, Models, Components, Patterns: 48th International Conference, TOOLS 2010, Málaga, Spain, June 28 - July 2, 2010, Proceedings". Here is a link to sample pages of the article :

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Objects_Models_Components_Patterns/hvzmnCtNffUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=moles+halleux&pg=PA253

Here is a link to the book :

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Objects_Models_Components_Patterns/hvzmnCtNffUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Objects,+Models,+Components&printsec=frontcover

Pex and Moles are mentioned in "Practical Microsoft Visual Studio 2015", "Real World .NET, C#, and Silverlight", "Agile Software Engineering with Visual Studio", "Pro .NET Best Practices". See "Pex and Moles - Isolation and White box Unit Testing for .NET" :

http://research.micvrosoft.com/projects/pex/

The latest URLs on Archive.org for the 3 videos are :

https://web.archive.org/web/20210917122427/http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-13

https://web.archive.org/web/20210917131545/http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-23

https://web.archive.org/web/20210917141034/http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-33

More videos with Peli de Halleux :

https://web.archive.org/web/20210514205423/https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Nikolai-Tillman-and-Peli-de-Halleux-Inside-Code-Digger

https://web.archive.org/web/20210624042526/https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/Pex-Unit-Testing-of-SharePoint-Services-that-Rocks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34383012)