# detouring calls in shims of fakes framework, what's its inside mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-fakes

i'm curious about detouring calls in shims of fakes framework. 
What's its inside mechanism or inner principle?
how does microsoft implement it?

Hoping for your help,thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I know, this is done by modifying the IL of the program and substituting the shim's properties if they have a delegate.

Comment: @Magus I always assumed there was a hook somewhere. Shims are significantly slower than 'regular' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fakes is a productised version of the Moles framework which came out of Microsoft Research. You can refer to the publicly available references for the Moles framework to get a handle on how Shims work.

In short the redirection is implemented using the .net profiler callbacks.

Refer

1. [You can see the explanation on stackoverflow for Moles from the creator of Moles himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021797/how-moles-isolation-framework-is-implemented/3068218#3068218)
2. [Pex and Moles Website](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/)
3. [Presentation which has some details by the creator of Moles](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/liese/TechDays-2010--Moles-Replace-any-NET-method-with-your-delegate)