# C# mutantion testing - change method runtime with il code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, il

You can skip to my approach if you don't mind what I'm actually trying to do.

**What I'm trying to do**
Hey I'm trying to make mutant testing, 
inspired by the talk
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/kill-better-test

But I'm using c# and the best mutant libraries are made in java such as 
http://pitest.org/

There are some frameworks for c# such as ninjaturtles and visualmutator,
but they both doesn't work in my computer for some reason(I get a weird error).
and also I thought it would be interesting creating my own.

**About mutant testing**
For those who doesn't know what is mutant testing,
it's a testing for the tests, most people use
code coverage to check that their test cover all the scenarios,
but it's not enough,
cause just because it gets to a piece of code doesn't mean it tests it.
It changes a piece of code, and if the tests still pass 
it means you didn't tested the piece of code.

**My approach**
So I've tried starting with a simple code 
that gets the il codes of a method.

```
        var classType = typeof(MethodClass);
        var methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("ExecuteMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        byte[] ilCodes = methodInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
```

this is the MethodClass I'm trying to change:

```
public class MethodClass
{
    private static int ExecuteMethod()
    {
        var i = 0;
        i += 5;
        if (i >= 5)
        {
            i = 2;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

now I'm trying to replace the ils

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ilCodes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ilCodes[i] == OpCodes.Add.Value)
            {
                ilCodes[i] = (byte)OpCodes.Sub.Value;
            }
        }
```

but then I'm not sure how to update my function to work with the new il codes.

I've tried using

```
        var dynamicFunction = new DynamicMethod("newmethod", typeof(int), null);
        var ilGenerator = dynamicFunction.GetILGenerator();
```

and then the il generator has a function emit, that gets operator and value, so I could use this. but I don't have the value to put in the emit..

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: The way that tools like Moles and Fakes do this is by intercepting the Il stream issued by the compiler using their own CLR profiler - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021797/how-moles-isolation-framework-is-implemented. There's a lot of stuff you'll need to take account of, and your major challenge is going to be mutating the code in a meaningful way (i.e. ensuring the il you write is valid C# - randomly mutating it without analytically based targeting won't really help you detect poor tests). I'd recommend trying to fix the error you're getting, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Thank you!
I've tried fixing the error but I don't have any clue,
I've downloaded the code from github and when running it I got
"unknown custom metadata item kind 6"
and I have no idea what it means, and I haven't managed to run it in debug mode.

Comment: Looking at the source code for VisualMutator, the exception you're talking about is thrown in this .cs: https://github.com/visualmutator/visualmutator/blob/4b114ab1121e814a1bf2e10336bd1ce5b2131b00/packages/CCI.1.0.13/src/Metadata/Sources/PdbReader/PdbFunction.cs, which seems to be reading the pdb file for an assembly. Without digging into it more, I can't give you too much advice on how to solve it. One useful bit of info I picked up reading some of the src was that it depends on Microsoft CCI - it may be worth checking out what you can do with that: https://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/.

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/141
I found this guy, which seems to have the same error with different project. 
He downgraded the cci package I think, and it fixed it for him, as far as I understood.
I might give it a shot.

Comment: Ok I don't think he's talking about exactly the same thing,
I'm already downgraded..

Comment: btw  in vs2013 I get this error:
http://i.imgur.com/J6OiVSr.png
it getter to further step in the testing.
It happens when I start a testing session, it can't run the tests for a reason(and I can run them)

Comment: it works! I'm not sure why lol.
maybe I still had a refrence for the MS testing framework instead of NUnit.
thanks a lot! Just the only problem is that he doesn't kill the proccess
and I can't save my files after starting a session.

Comment: Also it doesn't work with vs 2015 which really sucks.. cause I can't run it on projects that using c# 6

Comment: Ok I made a version that works with 2015. I'll make a pull request